# laravel excel export download

Tags: php, laravel, memory-limit

How to download excel with thousands of rows in laravel 4.
I am using Maatwebsite package.
I am getting following error.

> [2016-10-20 11:22:00] local.ERROR: exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message
>   'Allowed memory size of 524288000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   4194304 bytes)' 
>   #0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
>   #1 {main} [] []

I have set

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 2000);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2000M');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
```

**But this is a hack. You should find out some way to reduce the time and memory your script is taking.** There is always chance that things can be optimized.